# What class does an edit interface need to inherit from？

Tags: qt

[image]

I need to make an edit page as shown in the figure. Which class of QT should I inherit from? QDialog? QWizardPage? Or which class?

Comment: I would use `QDialog`, but don't assume that's the _right_ answer ... I looked for the `QWizard` class (which derives from `QDialog`), which is used for multiple pages, unlike your dialog. However, that doesn't mean you can't use the wizard dialog with only one page.

Comment: I don't see a point in using a one-page wizard, I'd go for QDialog with a QDialogButtonBox for the buttons at the bottom.